# Is there a list anywhere which shows all of the links between sounds chosen in words and their effect when spoken / read?

Tags: phrase-analysis

I am completing an English assignment where we have to analyse the effect that a text makes on the reader, but only referencing instances where certain phrases impress the reader because of choices in the sound of the word. Does anyone know of a good reference list which comprehensively covers links between the sound of the word / sounds used and the effect that is created?

[I know it's unlikely that such a list exists - I'm just holding out hope]

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like poetry, assonance, alliteration?  I think this question is way too broad.

Comment: The book is Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde - but Stevenson plays a lot with language and sound, for context, so apparently it's appropriate to examine sound choices.

Comment: Try Cooper and Ross's [_World Order_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf) for a general overview, or Ross's [_Languages as Poems_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Languagesaspoems.pdf) for a specific analysis of Williams' "The Red Wheel Barrow". This is probably not be what your teacher is expecting, but it's within the parameters of your question.

Comment: Thanks very much. The 'Languages as Poems' is definitely more readable than the other - but I'll use both to try and answer my question. It's quite a long period of time until I have to hand it in so I'll have time for some research.